# Binding DataTemplate to ItemsControl's ItemsSource

Tags: binding, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, datatemplate

If this question is already asked I can not find the correct search terms.

I have a view model with an Observable collection.

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<OperationMessage> PendingMessages { get; set; }
}
```

I set the view model in code behind of my page:

```
class MyPage : Page
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
        this.DefaultViewModel["MyViewModel"] = myViewModel;
    }
}
```

Additionally I have a UserControl with a property of type OperationMessage:

```
public class MachineMessages : UserControl
{
    public OperationMessage CurrentMessage { get; set; }
}
```

In MyPage.xaml.cs I want to create an ItemsControl and bind it to the ObservableCollection.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="MessageList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewModel.PendingMessages}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MyControls:MachineMessages DataContext="{Binding}" CurrentMessage="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

So for each item of type OperationMessage I want the ItemsControl to create a new user control - this works. But I also want to bind additionally each OperationMessage to the property CurrentMessage of the UerControl. So this line does not work:

```
<MyControls:MachineMessages DataContext="{Binding}" CurrentMessage="{Binding}" />
```

So how do I bind each item of the ObservableCollection to the property of the UserControl?

Thanks.

Comment: The `DataContext="{Binding}"` part is redundant. It is done by default anyway. In order to make the `CurrentMessage="{Binding}"` part work, `CurrentMessage` would have to be a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx). But why do you need this at all when the DataContext is already set to the current item?

Comment: The user control is used on many pages, also "stand-alone". Only in this case I would like to use it as the data template of an items control. So, for this reason the user control has it's own data context already set to RelativeSource=Self, which is used for internal handling. 

`<UserControl DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >`

Comment: @Clemens I have changed it to a dependency property and it still does not work. I would like to deliberately assign each item to the CurrentMessage property, not to the DataContext of the whole UserControl.

Answer (score 1):

The `CurrentMessage` property could simply return the `DataContext` object:

```
public class MachineMessages : UserControl
{
    public OperationMessage CurrentMessage
    {
        get { return DataContext as OperationMessage; }
    }
}
```

Your DataTemplate would look like this because you don't need to explicitly bind the DataContext:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <MyControls:MachineMessages />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```